# Create a file if the folder is empty

Tags: php, file, directory

I want create a file with some information if the folder is empty.
This is my script :

```
$fileList = glob('tpe*');
if (count(glob('$fileList/*')) == 0 ) {
    $key = 'index.html';
    $person = "<title> En cours </title> <p> Le site est en cours </p>";
    file_put_contents($key, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

the problem is that it creates me in the current directory and not in the empty directory.

Thanks for you help ;)

Comment: Where you set your directory to write into it?

Comment: mkdir to create a directory: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: change `if (count(glob('$fileList/*')) == 0 ) {` with `if (count(glob($fileList.'/*')) == 0 ) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in line 3, instead of

```
$key = 'index.html';
```

you should use:

```
$key = $fileList[0].'/index.html';
```

It will create file in that folder not in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code.

First of all, when you use single quotes in `glob('$fileList/*')`, it s literal string `$fileList/*`. There's no variable substitution.

If you want to put `$fileList` **value** into then string, you need to either use double quotes (`glob("$fileList/*")`), or concatenation (`glob($fileList . '/*')`)

Next error is that `glob()` returns array, so `$fileList` is an array, and that means that you cannot simply put it into a string.

Now, depending on what you really want to do, you may want to take any particular result from `glob()`, or iterate over all of them and do what you want on each of them.

I'll assume that you want to create `index.html` in each matched empty directory.

So it would be:

```
foreach($fileList as $filePath) {
    if (count(glob("$filePath/*")) == 0 ) {
       // rest of code
    }
}
```

Now, there's the clue of your problem. Your putting content into `index.html` file in current directory, because you don't tell `file_put_contents` where to do it.

The first argument is **path**, not just the filename. So when you passed `index.html` value, it's a relative path to current directory.

You need to pass whole path, which probably is `$filePath . "/index.html"`, so it would be:

```
$key = $filePath . "/index.html";
```

At the end I would like to notice, that you may need additional validation like if matched paths are indeed directories. Also working on relative paths is a little bit risky. It would be better to rely on absolute paths.